# SwiftUI creating a dictionary to hold different views

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I am experimenting building a pretty simple SwiftUI program to swap views easily. The goal is to make it as simple as possible to add more views without having to change the code that determines which view is how (so a standard `if-else` isn't going to work).

My current thinking is to keep a dictionary with views stored as part of a key-value pair. A very basic example of the implementation is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ViewA: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("This is View A")
  }
}

struct ViewB: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("This is View B")
  }
}

struct MainView: View {
  
  var subviews: [String:View] = [
    "View-1": ViewA(),
    "View-2": ViewB(),
  ]
  
  var body: some View {
    self.subviews["View-1"]
  }
}
```

I am however getting an error on the lines where I am creating the dictionary: `Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

I have tried a number of different types for the value part of the dictionary, including `AnyView`, `Groups`, and making a generic type `<Content: View>` on the MainView struct. These however give more/different errors.

I have looked at the project [SwiftUIRouter](https://github.com/frzi/SwiftUIRouter), as it kind of solves what I a trying to achieve, however my goals are a bit more simplistic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `AnyView` should work, but you'd need to wrap any view in `AnyView(ViewA())` to store it.

Comment: Thanks! Only issue is I’ve read that AnyView isn’t very efficient. Do you think it would effect the performance in a noticeable way?

Comment: My understanding is that if all views were just `AnyView` type (instead of the exact type that is achieved through the opaque `some View`) SwiftUI wouldn't know which view tree branch do not need to be recomputed. But if you need a router-like functionality where completely different view hierarchies need to be used, i think it's unavoidable that you'd need to use `AnyView`

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't have named subscripts, so you have to put it together hackily, but you can use the same calling syntax with otherwise useful/better language features:

```swift
struct MainView: View {
  var body: some View {
    subviews["View-1"]
  }
  
  enum subviews {
    @ViewBuilder static subscript(string: String) -> some View {
      switch string {
      case "View-1":
        ViewA()
      case "View-2":
        ViewB()
      default:
        fatalError()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jessy, but I don't really agree with you here. You are about to make a dictionary in Swift where the key is a String, or any other type of that matter. You just use the dictionary syntax as I did above. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary

Comment: I’m sorry but I don’t understand your wording. It seems like you think I don’t know what the Dictionary type is.